# Custom fetch() not working in Office Add-in

Tags: node.js, office365, office-js, office-addins

I have the following custom function to fetch

```
function myfunction(){
  fetch('https://api.jokes.one/jod?category=animal')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((myJson) => {
    return JSON.stringify(myJson);
  });
}
```

After fetching the data, I want them to be inserted in the word document:

```
export async function run() {
  return Word.run(async (context) => {

    var a = myfunction();

    const paragraph = context.document.body.insertParagraph(a, Word.InsertLocation.end);

    await context.sync();
  });
}
```

But when I tried to start the dev server to run the code, no data is inserted in the word document. Is there anything I have missed? I suspect it is some configuration settings to be made like CORS (which I am not quite sure why). It would be great if there is any explanation in detail thanks

Comment: Try defining `myFunction` with the `async` keyword. Then replace `var a = myfunction();` with `var a = await myfunction();`.

Comment: OK. I'll make this an answer. Please accept it so it will count as answered in Stack's statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `myfunction()` isn't complete when the later lines of code run. You need to add the `await` keyword, so that the next line of code will wait until the function is complete, like this:

```
var a = await myfunction();
```

Also, you need to define `myfunction()` with the `async` keyword so that you can await it.

Answer (score 0):

response.json() is more dependent on a promise structure, so you have to call then once again.

```
function myfunction(){
  fetch('https://api.jokes.one/jod?category=animal')
  .then((response) => {
    response.json().then(result => {
    return result;
    })      
  })
}
```